# How can I perform ABC analysis in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking to use R to run an ABC analysis also known as Pareto analysis. The ABC analysis is a business term used to define an categorization technique often used in materials management.

There are no fixed threshold for each class, different proportion can be applied based on objective and criteria. ABC Analysis is similar to the Pareto principle in that the 'A' items will typically account for a large proportion of the overall value but a small percentage of number of items.

Comment: maybe simply you can use `abc` package.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The qcc package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qcc/qcc.pdf) has a function pareto.chart which provides means to easily perform an ABC analysis in form of a table and chart output.

Answer (score 5):

In all seriousness, I think the `abc` package is coincidental naming of a common supply management technique.  The `abc` package creates a model of a known variable while the OP wants to create a classification variable based on a single known variable (revenue).  In the `abc` package, the record is classified based on the *value* of the variable; per the abc technique in question, the record is classified based on the value of the *aggregate*.  E.g. all part number 4132457 are classified as "A".

This is a plain vanilla calculation: you're no better off in R than you are in a spreadsheet.  If one insists on an R implementation, I would recommend something along the lines of:

```
library(plyr)
z <- data.frame(Part.Number =c(rep(letters[15:1], seq_along(letters[15:1]))), 
                Price = c(rep(1:15, seq_along(15:1))), 
                Qty.Sold = sample(1:120))
z[90:120, ]$Qty.Sold <- z[90:120, ]$Qty.Sold * 10 # creates fake data
z.summary <- ddply(z, .(Part.Number), summarise, 
                   Revenue = sum(Price * Qty.Sold)) # summarise fake data

z.summary <- within(z.summary, {
    Percent.Revenue <- cumsum(rev(sort(Revenue)))/sum(Revenue)
    ABC <- ifelse(Percent.Revenue > 0.91, "C",
           ifelse(Percent.Revenue < 0.81, "A", "B"))
})

z.summary
#    Part.Number Revenue Percent.Revenue ABC
# 1            a  140850       0.4461246   A
# 2            b  113960       0.8070784   A
# 3            c   21788       0.8760892   B
# 4            d    8220       0.9021250   B
# 5            e    7238       0.9250504   C
# 6            f    6390       0.9452900   C
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there's a dedicated R package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ABCanalysis/index.html) available doing this job.